# Changing transparency of Facebook share box

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-like

What CSS property should I change at [this](http://india.thefalljourney.com/2012/03/01/first-day) page to disable transparency of a share iframe which appears when `Like` button is clicked?

When you hover on that Facebook box after clicking `Like` button, it becomes partially transparent and if you move your cursor away from it, it becomes solid white. I want it to be completely opaque all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see no transparency on that box, only for the fade-in effect when it opens, but once it's fully opened it's not transparent.

To answer your question, you can see for yourself using firebug (firefox) or the development tools (chrome/safari) which css rules apply to what element.
From what I've seen now, you can use the use these: fb_edge_comment_widget fb_iframe_widget which are the classes of the *span* containing the iframe, or you can use the iframe itself.

The thing is though, is that you should not hack that. Why? Since then you'll have to always check for updates facebook are making, changes that they do not update you about (API changes they update on the blog), if you fail to be aware of these changes it can "break" your code/style.

Comment: Thanks for your response but there's still that problem that I mentioned. You say that there's no transparency but I still have it.
Try to click like, wait for the box to load and move your cursor away from the box, then move the cursor over the box once again and you'll see that it becomes translucent. And it happens to several people who visited my website and to myself as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the exact same problem.

I am using an [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) widget set, and I don't know if this was the case for you or not (it looks like you may have chosen a different solution as I can't see the Like button on your site).

I ended up using

```
.addthis_button_facebook_like {
     opacity:1 !important;
    }
```

but you would use whatever selector that wrapped your like button. if using the standard embed from Facebook, it would probably be

```
.fb-like {
     opacity:1 !important;
    }
```

Someone else was [having a similar problem](http://wilt.isaac.su/articles/facebook-send-button-pop-up-turns-transparent) with a Send button, which got me on the right track.

See it working like it ought to [here](http://www.camphighlander.local/blog/battle-of-the-flag-stars-and-stripes-has-begun-at-#.T_WyI3DFWKT). I'm sure it had something to do with some conflict from other styles, or possibly [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/), but it's working now!